# Which miners support generating their own midstate?

Tags: mining-pools, json-rpc, protocol, mining-software, mining-technical-details

Currently I was testing RPCMiner on my Mac running a custom pool, and it appears to crash because I can't generate a proper midstate value. Which miners support generating their own midstate (as per an [extension](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork#midstate) of the protocol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see which miners support what features here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork_support

"midstate" is the feature you are looking for in this case.